# Displaying Data in tree View on a php page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a site(Php and Javascript), On the Left side i want to dispaly categories and corresponding SubCategories.

The tree should be movable something like as on this link   http://www.xtlinks.com/articles/

Please suggest what should i do.

Comment: There is no tree on this website. Are you talking about their homepage http://www.xtlinks.com ? Then you can use multiple ULs

Comment: @NCode     i want to create the sane movable control  just like top categories covers the list of categories in the link provided

Comment: @nickb   i  am not getting from where should i start

Comment: @Mohit Movable = Collapsable ?

Comment: @ManseUK  yes i mean collapsable?

Comment: @Mohit I have updated my answer. You can use LI for lists and jQuery for the affect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/) - lots of good examples on there.

For the collapse affect look at the .slide() method of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

These two links explain the things really well.

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/listCollapseExample.html

http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/

or Simply try this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDisplayState(sBoxId)
    {
    if (document.getElementById) {
    oBox = document.getElementById(sBoxId).style;
    if (oBox.display == "none" || oBox.display == "NULL") {
    oBox.display = "block";
    } else {
    oBox.display = "none";
    }
    }
    }
</script>
</head>


<body>
        <ul>
<li>parent 1</li>
<li><a href="javascript:changeDisplayState('childset_1')">parent 2</a>
<ul id="childset_1">
<li><a href="javascript:changeDisplayState('grandchildset_1')">child 1</a>
<ul id="grandchildset_1">
<li>grandchild 1</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```